# Saving loops without overwriting data

Tags: python, csv

For a current project, I am running three loops for the JSON objects `'Text_Main'`,`'Text_Pro'` and `'Text_Con'`. The `print()` output in my terminal is correctly showing the consecutive results for all three iterations.

When saving the results in a CSV file, the script however starts overwriting the previous iterations and only saves the third iteration. Is there any way to have the loops appended to the previous loop, i.e. ending up with a CSV file that includes the results from all three iterations?

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
for i in ['Text_Main','Text_Pro','Text_Con']:
    common_words = get_top_n_trigram(df[i], 50)
    for word, freq in common_words:
        print(i, word, freq)

        with open('Glassdoor_A.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(["Section", "Word", "Frequency"])
            writer.writerows([i, word, freq] for word,freq in common_words)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested `for` loop, so for each word, freq in common_words, you open a new CSV writer.

More correct would be:

```
# Open the file to write to:
with open('Glassdoor_A.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    # Write headers
    writer.writerow(["Section", "Word", "Frequency"])
    # Loop over the JSON objects.
    for i in ['Text_Main','Text_Pro','Text_Con']:
        # Loop over the common words inside the JSON object
        common_words = get_top_n_trigram(df[i], 50)
        for word, freq in common_words:
            # Print and write row.
            print(i, word, freq)
            writer.writerow([i, word, freq])
```

Comment: Thanks for the good idea - this is looping the same script multiple times in the output though...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I am obtaining a CSV file that includes the same table manifold times

Comment: Ah, a tiny oversight. I have updated my answer, it should work now!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you open the file on each iteration. And, you can use the file parameter in print function.

```py
with open('Glassdoor_A.csv', 'a', , newline='') as file:
    for i in ['Text_Main','Text_Pro','Text_Con']:
        common_words = get_top_n_trigram(df[i], 50)
        for word, freq in common_words:
            print(i, word, freq, sep=',', file=file)
```